# Should I use webpack UglifyJSPlugin when using HtmlWebpackPlugin minify.minifyJS?

Tags: javascript, webpack

If you deep look at `HtmlWebpackPlugin` [documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#minification) in the mimification topic, you will see that you can set a custom minifier options [here](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference)

In `minifyJS`, it says

> Minify JavaScript in script elements and event attributes (uses UglifyJS)

Does this means that in my webpack plugins I don't need to use `UglifyJSPlugin`?
 What is better, use `UglifyJSPlugin`, set `minifyJS: true` or use both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this means that in my webpack plugins I don't need to use UglifyJSPlugin?

Yes.

> What is better, use UglifyJSPlugin, set `minifyJS: true` or use both?

All will produce exactly the same output. `minifyJS: true` is probably the easiest way though.